# Low level pixel access via pgmagick

Tags: python, graphicsmagick, pgmagick

I was wondering if it possible to perform low level pixel manipulations on an image via pgmagick.  In particular, I would like to mimic the functionality found in the C++ GraphicsMagick API shown here:

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#low-level-image-pixel-access

When I try the following:

```
import pgmagick
im = pgmagick.Image('cow.png')
pixel_cache = im.getPixels(0,0,100,100)
```

I get an error like the following:

```
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'getPixels'
```

What would be the equivalent functionality in pgmagick?

Comment: I share your pain indraniel. Apparently you tried to get answers on any possible internet forum/mailing list :) The documentation is not useful at all but I think it's a recent change, because many posts point to it as "very useful". I tried to find previous version of the page but to no avail.